# Error of undefined variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP and MySQL script to know how much we have debts and the total paid debts:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$arr[] = 0;
$paid = 0;
$inst = 0;
$sql = "SELECT patient_id, sum(project_cost) as 'cost' FROM patient_info WHERE payment_type = :pt GROUP BY patient_id";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':pt', "installment");
$stmt->execute();

$res = $stmt->fetchAll();
//$count = $stmt->rowCount();
foreach ($res as $row) 
{
    $sql2 = "SELECT sum(payment) as 'Paid' FROM debt
             WHERE  patient_id = :pid";
    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
    $stmt2->bindValue(':pid', $row['patient_id']);
    $stmt2->execute();

    $res2 = $stmt2->fetchAll();
    foreach($res2 as $r)
    {

        if($row['cost'] != $r['Paid'])
        {
            $paid = $paid + $r['paid']; 
        }
    }
    $inst = $inst + $row['cost'];
}

$arr = array("inst" => $inst, "paid" => $paid);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

The `$arr` is returned into success function of AJAX call.

But what I see is an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: paid in
>   C:\wamp\www\dentist\pages\get_total_debts.php on line 40

And I am seeing the result of $inst:

[image]

I tried to get the `$paid` inside the foreach loop but still getting the same error.

Comment: I think it should be `$paid = $paid + $r['Paid'];` (Capital P in Paid)

Comment: can you please share `get_total_debts.php` page line 40.

Comment: @Thamilan thanks. That is it. You can add it as an answer. Ohh, it was so easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `$paid = $paid + $r['Paid'];` (Capital P in Paid)

Answer (score 1):

you should change following code

```
$paid = $paid + $r['paid'];
```

to

```
$paid = $paid + $r['Paid'];
```

PHP is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

```
if($row['cost'] != $r['Paid'])
{
    $paid = $paid + $r['paid']; 
}
```

I noticed that the first `$r['Paid']` has a Capital `P`. Maybe that is the problem?